# How do I migrate from legacy visjs (4.21) to modern visjs?

Tags: migration, data-visualization, vis.js

I have working code written a couple of years ago using the old version of visjs (https://almende.github.io/vis/). I would like to switch to the new code base (https://visjs.org/).
My code uses Network, Timeline, Graph2D, and Dataset/Dataview.

Are there any instructions on migrating code from the old version to the new one?

Things I have found, so far:

- vis.moment is now moment from moment.js (with some minor changes in default parameters)
- network has moveNode (which is much nicer than the old way of updating x/y in a node).
- I needed to set a scale for the timeline to get around the problem of too many grid lines.

I would be happy with something that discusses migrating from 4.21 to 5.0.
My current issue is with getting the Timeline to show up,
so a migration guide for Timeline would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an MWE? It's difficult to give any advice with no idea about what is being migrated. To put it simply install the new packages and `import { DataSet } from "vis-data/peer";`, `import { Network } from "vis-network/peer";`, `import { Timeline, Graph2d } from "vis-timeline/peer";`…